# Exception at server while uploading image file using jersey client

Tags: image, jersey, client

**I am trying to send image file to server using jersey client. i am getting below error in server**

From my client application i am opening file which is stored in my local driver and passing it over using jersey client APIs.

```
    Feb 06, 2016 7:38:09 AM org.jvnet.mimepull.TempFiles createTempFile
SEVERE: Exception caught
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.TempFiles.createTempFile(TempFiles.java:139)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MemoryData.createNext(MemoryData.java:96)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.Chunk.createNext(Chunk.java:64)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead.addBody(DataHead.java:87)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEPart.addBody(MIMEPart.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.makeProgress(MIMEMessage.java:240)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.parseAll(MIMEMessage.java:181)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.getAttachments(MIMEMessage.java:106)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart
(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart
(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(Mult
iPartReaderClientSide.java:158)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(Mult
iPartReaderClientSide.java:85)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequ
est.java:490)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequ
est.java:555)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormD
ataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvide
r.java:122)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMeth
odDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatch
Provider.java:153)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMeth
odDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchPr
ovider.java:203)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDi
spatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethod
Rule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
ndPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(Resourc
eClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
ndPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(R
ootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponen
t.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
Container.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
Container.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpo
int.java:2476)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoin
t.java:2465)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\personal\apache-tomcat-7.0.61\t
emp\MIME8685830544490166217.tmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
        ... 56 more

Feb 06, 2016 7:38:09 AM org.jvnet.mimepull.TempFiles createTempFile
WARNING: Error invoking java.nio API, temp file (path: null, prefix:MIME, suffix
:null) being created using old java.io API.
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.TempFiles.createTempFile(TempFiles.java:152)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MemoryData.createNext(MemoryData.java:96)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.Chunk.createNext(Chunk.java:64)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead.addBody(DataHead.java:87)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEPart.addBody(MIMEPart.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.makeProgress(MIMEMessage.java:240)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.parseAll(MIMEMessage.java:181)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.getAttachments(MIMEMessage.java:106)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart
(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart
(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(Mult
iPartReaderClientSide.java:158)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(Mult
iPartReaderClientSide.java:85)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequ
est.java:490)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequ
est.java:555)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormD
ataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvide
r.java:122)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMeth
odDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatch
Provider.java:153)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMeth
odDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchPr
ovider.java:203)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDi
spatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethod
Rule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
ndPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(Resourc
eClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
ndPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(R
ootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponen
t.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
Container.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
Container.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpo
int.java:2476)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoin
t.java:2465)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

**My Server code:**

```
 @POST
    @Path("/image")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         TransactionHandler th = new TransactionHandlerImpl();
        boolean bol = th.saveFiletoDisk(uploadedInputStream,4545);
     if(bol){
        return Response.ok().build();
        }else{
             return Response.noContent().build();
        }
}
```

**Client Call**

```
public boolean uploadImage(long id){
   FileInputStream fis = null;
   boolean returnval = false;
   ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
   cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
   Client client = Client.create(cc);
   WebResource service = client.resource(Util.getServerIPAddress() + "/pos-1/rest");

        File file = new File("\\myphotos\\images\\"+id + ".png");
        FormDataMultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        multipart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
        multipart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
        ClientResponse response = service.path("image").type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class,multipart);
        if(response.getStatus() == 200){
            returnval = true;
        }
    return returnval;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\personal\apache-tomcat-7.0.61\t
emp\MIME8685830544490166217.tmp
```

The path **D:\personal\apache-tomcat-7.0.61\temp** does NOT exist. Create the temp directory. It should work.

Faced the same issue. And resolved through the way mentioned above.

Source: [https://www.garysieling.com/blog](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/fixing-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception)